# How to carry over an ID to a different table when inserting using PDO and MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to carry over the userID from the Student table to the assessment table when the student adds a new subject so their subjects remain unique to them from the userID they have.

However i can't seem to ask the right question to get the answer i am looking for so i am assuming i have to get them a unique session when they log in that is their userID.

I then proceeded to add a hidden input so when the form is submitted MySQL is getting that userID so it can be added in however it doesn't seem to work*...

*Everything works as it should however the userID field in the assessment table remains 0

Surely there is a more effective way around this..

Here is what i have done below..

Once logged in i create a session -

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID'];
```

My PDO + MySQL -

```
  $assessName = $_POST["assessName"];
  $assessSubject = $_POST['assessSubject'];
  $duedate = $_POST['duedate'];
  $userID = $_POST['userID'];


      $sql = "INSERT INTO assessment (assessName, assessSubject, duedate, userID) VALUES (:assessName, :assessSubject, :duedate, :userID)";
      $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $statement->bindValue(':assessName', $assessName);
      $statement->bindValue(':assessSubject', $assessSubject);
      $statement->bindValue(':duedate', $duedate);
      $statement->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
      $result = $statement->execute();
      $statement->closeCursor();


      header("location: ../view/success.php");
      return $result;
```

Form -

```
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Assessment Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assessName" name="assessName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assessSubject" name="assessSubject" placeholder="Enter Subject" required>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $Variable_error;?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="dateBox">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="duedate" placeholder="Choose Due Date" autocomplete="off" required>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php $_SESSION['userID'] ?> "/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input>

        </form>
```

Thanks!

EDIT -

Student Table

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE username = :username AND password = 
:password';
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
$count = $statement->rowCount();
return $count;
```

Comment: The student should be given a unique identifier i.e. studentNumber when the enrol. This will identify them throughout the system. The session variable will change each time they log and can not be used to identify the student.

Comment: *"I am trying to carry over the userID from the Student table to the assessment table"* - Where is the code for the "Student" table? However and I'll try and guess here; but I think what you are probably are looking for is `last_insert_id()`. If so and you don't have both id columns set as an auto_increment, it would be required to use this function, should this be what the question is about.

Comment: Yup that is what i have done, is there a way to carry that unique identifier to a different table

Comment: @JackWarren please ping someone directly when someone posts a comment. That way they know you're talking about what "they" posted. Same thing goes for me if you want to reply to what I also said. Bit of a "Stack pro tip".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry about that will do from now on, Added code for student table, ahh so i should probably get rid of the Assessment ID as it isnt needed and use the userID as the primary aswell?.. for the assessment table that is

Comment: @JackWarren No worries. Now, I don't see a session array for the query in the "Student" table's query. If you haven't anything yet, then you would assign it to a session array of the same name you have now to the related row. *But*, you   would need to assign a variable from the (successfully) fetched query in probably some form of loop.

Comment: @JackWarren `value="<?php $_SESSION['userID'] ?> "` - for the life of me, I can't seem to remember if that (also) needs to be echo'd, so if that session array is assigned somewhere, use `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?> "`. I've been taking a break from coding for a while *lol*. and make sure the session was started in that page and all others using sessions.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes it definitely needs to be `<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>` or `<?= $_SESSION['userID']; ?>`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the students table query is in the same file as the the login so creating a session there would be unnecessary as i have it set so if the login is successful create it.. I have a feeling that is something to do with $_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID']; i wonder if this is the correct way to grab from the table

Comment: @JackWarren The way sessions works with logins Jack is this: 1) Person logs in via a form. 2) Login successful, assign a session array to an input. 3)  Use the session array for any further use and using that as the argument for an UPDATE query if one is to be used. In your case, you're using an INSERT. For your form with the hidden input using a session array, you need to echo it and using a ternary operator for it. Then you change your `$userID = $_POST['userID'];` to `$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];`, give that a try. Look at the HTML source in the form to see if the session array has value.

Comment: ... and use a conditional statement to  check if it's set, and/or not empty, then perform the query. Edit: Remember to destroy the session using a logout file also. Otherwise, the same session id will keep on being used.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks again for you help much appreciated the issue was within the students table... This is a little offtopic but do you know of any good PHP + PDO books that are going around?

Comment: Welcome Jack. As for books; sorry I don't. Glad to see you posted the answer for your solution, *cheers!*

Answer (score 1):

So my issue laid in my Student Table i needed to add

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $result[0]['studentid'];
```

Before my $count variable was used...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE username = :username AND password = :password';
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$_SESSION['uid'] = $result[0]['studentid'];
$statement->closeCursor();
$count = $statement->rowCount();
return $count;
```